# How to simplify $\cos(\frac{1}{3}\cos^{-1}(x))$ and $\sin(\frac{1}{3}\cos^{-1}(x))$?

Tags: trigonometry

How to simplify this trigonometric expression
$$
\cos \left(\frac{1}{3} \cos ^{-1}(b)\right)
$$

I want to write this equation as
$$
\cos \left(\frac{1}{3} \cos ^{-1}(b)\right) = \cos(\cos^{-1}(B)) = B
$$
Where $B$ is written in terms of $b$.
I couldn't find any identity that would let me do it.

This term appears in the solution of the depressed cubic equation as given in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Trigonometric_solution_for_three_real_roots).

In the original equation, the term is like
$$
\cos\left(\frac{1}{3}\cos^{-1}(b) - \frac{2\pi n}{3}\right) \\
= \cos\left(\frac{1}{3}\cos^{-1}(b)\right)\cos\left(\frac{2\pi n}{3}\right)+\sin\left(\frac{1}{3}\cos^{-1}(b)\right)\sin\left(\frac{2\pi n}{3}\right)
$$

Here the only term that are bothering me are only those $\cos\left(\frac13\cos^{-1}(b)\right)$ and $\sin\left(\frac13\cos^{-1}(b)\right)$

Comment: Why do you want to write it like that? Part of some equation?

Comment: yes, @user675453. I've edited the question, please have a look

Comment: Well, as the other users have pointed out. It can't be simplified more, Just adding to their answers, $B$ must be in $[\frac{1}{2},1]$ as LHS lies in $[0,\pi]$

Answer (score 1):

Let $y=\frac13\cos^{-1}(b)$ then $\cos(3y)=b$. Which gives $4\cos^3y-3\cos y=b$. Hence your $B$ is a solution of $
4x^3-3x-b=0$.

Comment: Yes, but which one? That cubic can have 3 real solutions.

Comment: I don't know. This can be determined when a fixed $b$ is given.

Comment: Looks to me that any method that would determine the root for fixed $b$ should also work for the variable $b$.

Comment: For $x \ge -1$ we can write
$\cos \left(\frac{1}{3} \text{arccos}(x)\right)=\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt[3]{x+i \sqrt{1-x^2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x+i \sqrt{1-x^2}}}\right)$. If this is a simplification is a matter of taste.

Answer (score 0):

Use trig. identity $$4\cos^3x-3\cos x=\cos 3x$$
substitute $x=\frac13\cos^{-1}b$
$$4\cos^3\left(\frac13\cos^{-1}b\right)-3\cos\left(\frac13\cos^{-1}b\right)=b$$
$$4B^3-3B-b=0$$
Solve above cubic equation for $B$ i.e. $\cos\left(\frac13\cos^{-1}b\right)$

Comment: Yes, but which one? That cubic can have 3 real solutions.

Comment: Well, because $\cos(\theta)\in [-1,1]$ hence  $-1\le B\le 1$

Comment: Still doesn't eliminate the extras. I mean, try $b = 0$ for illustration.

Comment: OK, for $b=0$ (also $-1\le b\le 1$), $$B=\cos\left(\frac13\cos^{-1}b\right)=\cos\left(\frac13\cos^{-1}0\right)=\cos\left(\frac13\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\implies -1\le B\le1$$

Comment: You could use $\cos^{-1}b \in [0,\pi] \implies \cos(\frac 13 \cos^{-1}b) \in [\frac 12, 1]$. That looks to me like it will eliminate the other 2 solutions.

Comment: Yes, absolutely right

Comment: Ok, let me complete the argument for those that are interested. The cubic attains local extrema at $\pm\frac 12$, so the three (not necessarily distinct) real roots lie in the segments $[-1,-\frac 12], [-\frac 12, \frac 12], [\frac 12, 1]$. In conjunction with the above comments, it means that $\cos\left(\frac13\cos^{-1}b\right)$ is the largest of the three roots.

Comment: @Ennar, following this page http://www.sosmath.com/algebra/factor/fac11/fac11.html  I got $$t^3=\dfrac{\frac{-b}{4}\pm \sqrt{\frac{b^2}{16}-\frac{1}{16}}}{2}$$ but $b \in [-1,1]$ that means this equation is only valid at two points?

Comment: @user675453, something probably went wrong in your derivation. The point is that you can just look at $f(x) = 4x^3-3x$ which has $3$ real roots $0$ and $\pm\frac{\sqrt 3}2$. Also, at local extrema $\pm\frac 12$ you get values $\pm 1$. That means that if you add $b\in[-1,1]$ to $f$, your graph doesn't shift enough to get non-real roots.

Comment: @Ennar, all I  did is substitute the values. What could possibly go in wrong in that. Seems like the imaginary part will cancel out?

Comment: @user675453, ah, ok, I misunderstood the notation, I thought $t$ was referring to a root. There is no problem, then. As you said, imaginary parts will cancel out.

"What could possibly go in wrong in that." Haha, you are overly optimistic there :D